# Input field is behind ion-footer when keyboard is active using capacitorJS accessibility bar enabled to show

Tags: ionic-framework, input, keyboard, capacitor

I am using capacitorJS keyboard plugin and showing the accessory bar.

`Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible({ isVisible: true });`

I also have a fixed ion-footer. Inside ion-content I have input fields. When i click inside an input field at the bottom of the page and the keyboard is active, ion-content scrolls up keeping the input field above the keyboard . This works fine with the fixed-footer, but when i add the accessory bar, the input field is behind the ion-footer (see blue cursor on image). I tried the following with no luck.

```
ion-content {
    --keyboard-offset: 100px!important;
}
```

[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zp7Y.png)